# convert structured string to values array with special symbols

Tags: php, arrays

This string is output from another system. I want to convert this data to a php array to make some thing in database.

so How do I convert structured string to values array with special symbols?

> [pending] America,Canada,Brazil,
>
> [active] Asia,Australia,
>
> [nonactive] India,Egypt,

i want to read this data to output like array php:

```
$pending = array("America","Canada","Brazil");
$active = array("Asia","Australia");
$notActive= array("India","Egypt");
```

I have tried using : `parse_ini_string` , `strstr` , `strpos` but they didn't work.

I did not find a brief idea. can you help me

Answer (score 1):

For your provided strings, you could use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to return the part in the string after the closing bracket and the whitespace `]`.
Then use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) with a comma as a delimiter and use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove the empty entries in the array (Because the string still has a comma at the end which gives an empty entry)

```
$strings = [
    "[pending] America,Canada,Brazil,",
    "[active] Asia,Australia,",
    "[nonactive] India,Egypt,"
];

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    preg_replace('/^(\[[^]]+]\s*)(.*)(,)$/', '\2', $string);
    preg_match_all("/(\w+),/", $string, $matches);
    $result = $matches[1];

    // This will be your array with your values
    var_dump($result);
}
```

[Output php](https://3v4l.org/MQEEA)

Another option be to use a regex with [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

[`^(\[[^]]+]\s*)(.*)(,)$`](https://regex101.com/r/u7QRjg/1/)

You could capture 3 groups. Then in the replacement, you use only group 2 `\2` which contains your data.

**Explanation**:

- From the beginning of the string `^`
- Group 1 - The data including the brackets and the following whitespace `(\[[^]]+]\s*)`
- Group 2 - The data you are looking for `(.*)`
- Group 3 - The comma at the end `(,)`
- The end of the string `$`

The first group will contain the data including the brackets and the following whitespace, the second group will contain the data you are looking for and the third group contains the comma.

```
foreach ($strings as $string) {
    preg_replace('/^(\[[^]]+]\s*)(.*)(,)$/', '\2', $string);
    preg_match_all("/(\w+),/", $string, $matches);
    $result = $matches[1];

    // This will be your array with your values
    var_dump($result);
}
```

[Output php](https://3v4l.org/RLbKU)

Answer (score -1):

use json_decode() function

check this link for details: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Thanks . but i want other solution .